# Calling SoapAction via PHP Curl

Tags: php, soap, curl

I want to reconnect my Router via PHP.

The Console Command is the following:

```
curl "http://192.168.178.1:49000/upnp/control/WANIPConn1" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"" -H "SoapAction: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#ForceTermination" -d ""
```

How can I do this with `curl` in PHP?

Comment: it would be much simpler if you just used the SOAP functions within PHP and not CURL. See http://www.php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: Actually the SOAP extension is not supported since 2010, there are other clients: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009115/php-which-soap-lib-to-use

Answer (score 0):

```php
$sPostfields ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\r\n"
        ."<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n"
        ."<s:Body>\r\n"
        ."<u:ForceTermination xmlns:u=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1\" />\r\n"
        ."</s:Body>\r\n"
        ."</s:Envelope>\r\n";
$soap_do = curl_init();

$header = array(
        "Content-Type: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: \"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#ForceTermination\"",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($sPostfields),
);

curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://192.168.178.1:49000/upnp/control/WANIPConn1" );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $sPostfields);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header );

$output = curl_exec($soap_do);
$aInfo = curl_getinfo($soap_do);
curl_close($soap_do);
print_r( $output );
print_r( $aInfo );
exit();
```

as per OP @angelmedia's edit on the question.