# Consuming web service from PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, biztalk, soapui

I am consuming a service from PHP and am also using SOAP UI to test.

Both Soap UI and consuming the service in the browser works fine however my client is saying that when we run this in the browser it is not hitting BizTalk. However when we run it from SOAP UI it is hitting BizTalk.

I have hidden the customer urls

My code is below.

```
$xml_data ='<soapenv:Envelope      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
           <ns0:FacilityAndProgramBookings      xmlns:ns0="<<<<<Customer URL>>>>>>">
    <BookingTransactions>
     <Action>A</Action> 
   <Venue>VenueV</Venue> 
   <Event_Type>Event_</Event_Type> 
  <Event_Category>Eve</Event_Category> 
  <StartDateTime>1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00</StartDateTime> 
  <EndDateTime>1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00</EndDateTime> 
  <BookingID>BookingIDBookingIDBo</BookingID> 
  <TransactionID>TransactionIDTransactionIDTransactionIDTransaction</TransactionID> 
  <TransactionDateTime>1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00</TransactionDateTime> 
  <Amount>10.4</Amount> 
  </BookingTransactions>
  </ns0:FacilityAndProgramBookings>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>';


$URL = "<<<<<URL>>>>>>>";

        $ch = curl_init($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
                    echo"$output";
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: "Both Soap UI and consuming the service in the browser works fine however my client is saying that when we run this in the browser it is not hitting BizTalk." - can you clarify this sentence?

Comment: We are posting data and when we do it through the code above it does not hit Biztalk. but if we put the xml into SOAP UI then it hits the BizTalk server

Comment: Ohh, so the problem is probably with the cURL code.

Comment: Btw why don't you use a PHP SOAP client, for example Zend2/SOAP or BeSimple? Maybe that would fix the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009115/php-which-soap-lib-to-use
in your case the code of BeSimple would help I think, because it overrides the buggy SOAP extension with cURL, so if there are special settings you will know that from BeSimple's code. It is here: https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSoap/blob/master/src/BeSimple/SoapClient/Curl.php

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327843/calling-soapaction-via-php-curl
I don't want to add a possible duplicate flag, because ppl usually click on close blindly by that...

Comment: You use template strings strangely, in your code the `"` around `"$xml_data"` and `"$output"`. If you want to convert something into string, you should use `(string) $output` by simple variables and `var_export($output, true)` by complex variables (which do not have __toString). `CURLOPT_MUTE` is invalid since php 5.2

Comment: Try these: `curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml_data))); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);`
and if you have an error message, then `$err = curl_error($ch);`
Currently I can send only tips, it is hard to debug something remotely... I guess the answer is there in an error message... For example you don't have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in your xml data, you don't have charset by your content type header, you don't have a SOAPAction header etc... It can be many things.